# S3 Select Query JSON for nested value when keys are dynamic

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-s3-select

I have a JSON object in S3 which follows this structure:

```
<code> : {
    <client>: <value>
}
```

For example,

```
  {
      "code_abc": {
          "client_1": 1,
          "client_2": 10
      },
      "code_def": {
          "client_2": 40,
          "client_3": 50,
          "client_5": 100
      },
      ...
}
```

I am trying to retrieve the **numerical value** with an S3 Select query, where the "code" and the "client" are populated dynamically with each query.

So far I have tried:

```
sql_exp = f"SELECT * from s3object[*][*] s where s.{proc}.{client_name} IS NOT NULL"
sql_exp = f"SELECT * from s3object s where s.{proc}[*].{client_name}[*] IS NOT NULL"
```

as well as without the asterisk inside the square brackets, but nothing works, I get `ClientError: An error occurred (ParseUnexpectedToken) when calling the SelectObjectContent operation: Unexpected token found LITERAL:UNKNOWN at line 1, column X` (depending on the length of the query string)

Within the function defining the object, I have:

```
resp = s3.select_object_content(
    Bucket=<bucket>,
    Key=<filename>,
    ExpressionType="SQL",
    Expression=sql_exp,
    InputSerialization={'JSON': {"Type": "Document"}},
    OutputSerialization={"JSON": {}},
)
```

Is there something off in the way I define the object serialization? How can I fix the query so I can retrieve the desired numerical value on the fly when I provide ”code” and “client”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tinkering based on the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-select.html), and it works!

I need to access the single event in the `EventStream` (`resp`) as follows:

```
event_stream = resp['Payload']
# unpack successful query response
for event in event_stream:
    if "Records" in event:
        output_str = event["Records"]["Payload"].decode("utf-8")  # bytes to string
        output_dict = json.loads(output_str)  # string to dict
```

Now the correct SQL expression is:

```
sql_exp= f"SELECT s['{code}']['{client}'] FROM S3Object s"
```

where I have gotten (dynamically) my values for `code` and `client` beforehand.
For example, based on the dummy JSON structure above, if `code = "code_abc"` and `client = "client_2"`, I want this S3 Select query to return the value `10`.

The f-string resolves to `sql_exp = "SELECT s['code_abc']['client_2'] FROM S3Object s"`, and when we call `resp`, we retrieve `output_dict = {'client_2': 10}` (Not sure if there is a clear way to get the value by itself without the client key, this is how it looks like in the documentation as well).

So, the final step is to retrieve `value = output_dict['client_2']`, which in our case is equal to `10`.

Comment: Hey @nvergos excellent! You could find a way to retrive the keys of the file? like "code_abc" and "code_def" in the example. Thanks